# Send Email Poweshell

Tags: powershell

I have an power shell script as below.
The output of the script will be like this:

```
Index     UserID        VirtualProxy    SessionID    VirtualProxyPrefix
1        Mike.Milbur        devf          dedff        eeee
2        Mark.Green         devf          dedff        eeee
```

Now, after the below script ends and from the table output, I want to send an email to the userID's. I know to send email manually, but how do I loop through the UserID's and send to everyone in the UserID list.
If some one can please help me that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Connect-Qlik|Out-Null 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$sessions = @()

foreach ($vp in Get-QlikVirtualProxy) { 
    foreach ($session in Get-QlikSession -virtualProxyPrefix $vp.prefix) { 

        $s = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Index              = "[$($sessions.Count+1)]" 
            UserId             = $session.UserId
            VirtualProxy       = $vp.description        
            SessionId          = $session.SessionId
            VirtualProxyPrefix = $vp.prefix
        }

        $sessions.Add($s)|Out-Null
    }
}

$sessions | Format-Table
```

Comment: take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I saw that before. I am able to send email using the below script. But I don't know how to incorporate the below script to send email by dynamically picking the userID from the table output. $PSEmailServer = 'relay.domain.local'

Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <noreply@domain.com>' -To 'User02 <user1@domain.com>' -Subject 'Test mail'